# Compiling F77 with R CMD SHLIB for use in R package. Changing `-fmax-stack-var-size=`

Tags: r, fortran, fortran77

I've inherited some F77 code from the 1980s that I'd like to eventually use in an R package that is on CRAN. Basically I'll be substituting a slow function written in straight R with a `.Call` to a F77 subroutine that runs 100x faster. I've done similar heavy lifting with C in the past. However, when I compile the fortran subroutine via `R CMD SHLIB` I get a warning about one of the arrays being "larger than limit set by '-fmax-stack-var-size='". I can fix this by compiling explicitly with `gfortran` and setting `-fmax-stack-var-size` appropriately. However, how can I set the flag when running `R CMD SHLIB`? In a `Makevars` file? Eventually, I'll include this in a new release and submit to CRAN and I want to head off any issues. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in `~/.R/Makevars` for *your* compilations, in `src/Makevars` for all builds of the package.  CRAN has views on which options are portable so you may not be able to ship with the option in `src/Makevars`.

Here is what I have:

```
edd@rob:~$ grep ^F .R/Makevars 
FLAGS=-Wall -O3 -g -pipe $(PEDANTIC) $(XTRAFLAGS)
FFLAGS=-O3 -g0 -Wall -pipe
FCFLAGS=-O3 -g0 -Wall -pipe
FC=$(CCACHE) gfortran
F77=$(CCACHE) gfortran
F95=$(CCACHE) gfortran
edd@rob:~$
```

where some of the other values are previoysly set as you can surmise.  Note that there are several Fortran compiler variables, details as usual in *Writing R Extensions*.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. It takes me time to work up the courage to crack open Writing R Extensions but I'll try to be brave. I've never included a fortran subroutine in an R package and I'm expecting that it'll be painful.

Comment: Naa, R has supported that since day one.  NetLib and StatLib and all that.